# FLUTTER Help me with if else

Tags: if-statement

I have output from firebase such strings: qs['email'], qs['username']
I want the effect of the output to be like this:

what I want

```
Text(
qs['email']
? qs['email'] == null output qs['username']
: qs['email'] and qs['username'] == isNoEmpty output qs['username'],
),
```

Help me put it together into the correct expression!

I tried doing it this way

```
Text(
qs['email']
? qs['email'] == null
: qs['username']
```

But it looks really dumb)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, came to it myself, thanks for the help)

```js
qs['email'].isEmpty ? qs['username'] : qs['email'],
```